# Python - schedule with random delay

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, random, schedule

I'am learning python by doing little projects on my own. I'am struggling  to schedule scripts with random delay in a range.
In the code below, the delay is random but always the same ... I Really need help.

```
import schedule
import time
import random
import datetime


def job():
    t = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
    print(str(t) + "  hello")


i = 0
while i < 10:
    delay = random.randrange(1, 5)
    schedule.every(delay).seconds.do(job)
    i += 1

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think through your loops.  Your first while loop creates a second infinite while loop.  So you never continue to the function that would create a new delay.

```
import schedule
import time
import random
import datetime


def job():
    t = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
    print(str(t) + "  hello")


i = 0
for i in range(10):
    delay = random.randrange(1, 5)
    print(delay)
    schedule.every(delay).seconds.do(job)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(.01)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it's not working. I found this instead by reading documentation of Schedule module: **schedule.every(90).to(150).minute.do(job)**, witch select a random number between 90 to 150, in this exemple

Comment: Yes that would work as well.  My attempt was to show you your problem in your code, not develop a better solution.

Comment: i am gratefull,  this help me, my friend.